# MingW missing some functions from the Win32 Crypto API

Tags: c++, winapi, cryptography, mingw

I need to use some functions from the Win32 Crypto API, such as CryptQueryObject. The problem is that I also need to compile my program with MingW and the crypto library included is missing some of the functions that I need, like the aformentioned CryptQueryObject. I tried copying the relevant C header definitions, so that the program now compiles, but at link time it fails with undefined reference errors (since mingw's crypt32.dll doesn't implement some functions). I tried linking against C:\Windows\System32\crypt32.dll, but it still returns linking errors.

Is there a way to use the entire Crypto API in mingw?

Comment: Why not download the [entire Windows SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8279)? Surely you can use that from MinGW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to dynamically link to crypt32.dll. You can either do this at runtime
using Win32 API functions [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) + [GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx), or at compile time using an [import library](https://web.archive.org/web/20200504021857/http://www.mingw.org/wiki/CreateImportLibraries).

For runtime binding, MSDN has a [good example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686944(v=vs.85).aspx).

**EDIT:** If you need a bunch of API functions not present in MinGW's headers, go for the import library.

Comment: Another good example is in the openssl library in the file /crypto/rand/rand_win.c

Comment: This is bad advice. Don't mix Microsoft's SDK/MSDN with MinGW. If the functions are missing in your MinGW it's because it's too old. Use newer MinGW-w64 instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Download and install the [Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk).

Now call the linker:

```
gcc -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.14393.0\um\arm" -o "Test"  ./main.o -lcrypt32
```

Comment: No, don't mix MinGW with Microsoft's SDK. That will mess up things more as there are 2 different implementations that should bot be mixed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using an old version of MinGW, because the crypto stuff is present in recent versions like MinGW-w64. Get the latest version via MSYS2's package manager `pacman` or use a standalone build from https://winlibs.com